# QtCreator opens links in new split

Tags: qt-creator

There is an option in QtCreator that makes it open a new split when you do CTRL + click on some function, Class, etc (even if it's in the same file). I activated it long time ago but I can't remember where it is in the UI to disable it. It's really annoying when I'm using a small screen.

I'm using QtCreator 3.0.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is in `Options` -> `Text Editor` -> `Display`. The setting is called `Always open links in another split`

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl+Alt+click/ Ctrl+click works on qtcreator 4.8.2. With this shortcut, you can dynamicly switch which way you prefer to open the link.